# Force centroid initialization to array in k-means with sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I am working on an anomaly detection project, and for that I have embeddings which contain features from images (adversarial autoencoder model). Now I want to interpret these embeddings with PCA and k-means. I need to find certain embeddings of features in the images that allow me to distinguish between two datasets of images.

With `scikit-learn`, k-means is pretty easy, but the centroid initialization is almost always done randomly. I already know the means of the datasets I want to apply k-means to, so no random initialization is needed. How can I force the `sklearn` k-means function to initialize the centroids to an array of means?

The initilialization can be done by passing of through the `init` parameter, but the only examples on the sklearn documentation site use `init='k-means++'`. The library source code doesn't have an example either

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states that you can pass an array-like as init argument when calling the function

"[...] init{‘k-means++’, ‘random’}, callable or array-like of shape (n_clusters, n_features), default=’k-means++’
Method for initialization:", (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) meaning something like
`your_centroids = np.random.randn(8, 3)`
`k_means = sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=8, init=your_centroids)`
should work (not tested).